# Sql variable table name in stored procedure error

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to create procedure and I get the following error;

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'select ID into#a
>   from @table Where yil=' to data type int.

How can write proper procedure? My procedure;

```
@tablo nvarchar(100),
@kayit nvarchar(50),
@inceleme nvarchar(50),
@icevap nvarchar(50),
@tespit nvarchar(MAX),
@scevap nvarchar(MAX),
@aksiyon nvarchar(50),
@mutalaa nvarchar(MAX),
@tamamlanma nvarchar(100),
@not nvarchar(MAX),
@izleme nvarchar(50),
@kaydeden nvarchar(50),
@idd int,
@kullanici nvarchar(50),
 @yil int,
@donem int

as

DECLARE @sql as varchar(max)
SET @sql = 'select ID into #a from' + @tablo+
' Where yil='+@yil+' and donem='+@donem+' and (ilkkaydeden is 
null or ilkkaydeden='') and (kull='+@kullanici+' or 
kull1='+@kullanici+' or kull2='+@kullanici+')'
EXEC(@sql)
```

Comment: Please add the code where the variables you are using is handled. What datatype is @yil? Is it int? If so, you might need to cast it as nvarchar. I.e. `yil='+CAST(@yil as nvarchar)`. Also, you might be missing an `AND` here: `+@yil+'donem=`

Answer (score 0):

You have two variables as integer `@yil` & `@donem` and you cannot concatenate them without converting them to `varchar` or `nvarchar` first.

use the next code:-

```
DECLARE @sql as varchar(max)
SET @sql = 'select ID into #a from' + @tablo+
' Where yil='+convert(nvarchar(20),@yil)+' and donem='+convert(nvarchar(20),@donem)+' and (ilkkaydeden is 
null or ilkkaydeden='') and (kull='+@kullanici+' or 
kull1='+@kullanici+' or kull2='+@kullanici+')'
EXEC(@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

For INT values, declare as INT, then when creating your dynamic sql, use

```
  CONVERT(VARCHAR, @var)
```

For char values, add extra quotes like this:

```
 '...var='''+@char_var+''' more text..'
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't write your stored procedures as you do now, they're vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. Rewrite them using parameterized queries, they'll be safe :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test
    @tablo NVARCHAR(100)
  , @kayit NVARCHAR(50)
  , @inceleme NVARCHAR(50)
  , @icevap NVARCHAR(50)
  , @tespit NVARCHAR(MAX)
  , @scevap NVARCHAR(MAX)
  , @aksiyon NVARCHAR(50)
  , @mutalaa NVARCHAR(MAX)
  , @tamamlanma NVARCHAR(100)
  , @not NVARCHAR(MAX)
  , @izleme NVARCHAR(50)
  , @kaydeden NVARCHAR(50)
  , @idd INT
  , @kullanici NVARCHAR(50)
  , @yil INT
  , @donem INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @tablo = (   SELECT FORMATMESSAGE('%s.%s', QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(O.schema_id)), QUOTENAME(O.name))
                     FROM sys.objects AS O
                     WHERE O.object_id = OBJECT_ID(@tablo, 'U'));

    SET @sql = N'
        SELECT ID
        INTO #a
        FROM ' + @tablo + '
        WHERE yil = @yil
        AND donem = @donem
        AND (ilkkaydeden IS NULL OR ilkkaydeden = '')
        AND @kullanici IN (kull, kull1, kull2);';

    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql, N'@yil INT, @donem INT, @kullanici NVARCHAR(50)', @yil, @donem, @kullanici;
END;
```

And if you must insert table name dynamically, wrap it into `QUOTENAME()` function, it will wrap your variable into square brackets and make it a valid object name.

In this case I even check if `@tablo` table exists and assign it a proper value, which is a mix of schema and table and is safe to use.

Answer (score -2):

Update(after comments): *Just cast then **int** variables to **varchar** in order for concatenation to work*

```
DECLARE @tablo NVARCHAR(100)
    , @kayit NVARCHAR(50)
    , @inceleme NVARCHAR(50)
    , @icevap NVARCHAR(50)
    , @tespit NVARCHAR(MAX)
    , @scevap NVARCHAR(MAX)
    , @aksiyon NVARCHAR(50)
    , @mutalaa NVARCHAR(MAX)
    , @tamamlanma NVARCHAR(100)
    , @not NVARCHAR(MAX)
    , @izleme NVARCHAR(50)
    , @kaydeden NVARCHAR(50)
    , @idd INT
    , @kullanici NVARCHAR(50)
    , @yil INT
    , @donem INT
DECLARE @sql AS VARCHAR(max)

SET @sql = 'select ID into #a from' + @tablo + ' Where yil=' + cast(@yil as varchar) + ' and donem=' +  cast(@donem as varchar) + ' and (ilkkaydeden is 
null or ilkkaydeden='') and (kull=' + @kullanici + ' or 
kull1=' + @kullanici + ' or kull2=' + @kullanici + ')'

EXEC (@sql)
```

Comment: Although this may answer the question, some comments and/or explanation would be nice. That will help other users as well.

Comment: @JanesAbouChleih Fine here goes; _Just cast then **int** variables to **varchar** in order for concatenation to work._